# AnimatedVectorDrawable is not running on Android 8.0.0

Tags: android, animatedvectordrawable

I have been testing the [AnimatedVectotDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable) API to animate vector-drawables and it only shows the end of the animation when I run it on an Android 8.0.0 physical device (No animation).

I have testest on an Android Q AVD and it works fine. Here is my Gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nic"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

Please advise if I am missing something

Comment: Had a read here?https://stackoverflow.com/q/35480074/1133011

Comment: I have tried the. Still not working.

Comment: Okay well I'd suggest posting a short code sample that demonstrates this, might be something wrong there at least its easier for anyone wanting to help you replicate the problem

Comment: If anyone has an Android 8.0.0 device, please try an animation with the build script above incase its just my device with the problem

Comment: Also try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41872908/1133011?

Comment: Try an emulator running android 8? If that replicates the real world device issue it's very likely a bug

Comment: Noted, will download an emulator to try it out